# Xaml DatePicker default and earliest date available for selection settings in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, datepicker

I have couple of `datepicker` implemented in `Xaml` .
- After user picks certain dates, a simple logic finds the earliest of the two dates. Also, it is not necessary for user to pick both dates.

I noticed that the "default" `datepicker` value if user does not pick any date is `1/1/0001`.

Assuming the user picks the second date as 1/1/2017, the earliest of the two dates would always be 1/1/0001 which is not desired. In such scenario, the minimum date should be 1/1/2017.

what is the logic to neglect default date of 1/1/0001

Comment: The DatePicker selected date is a nullable DateTime so you can bind to a nullable DateTime and then check for null (unset) before comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property `MinYear` which can be set to minimum year accepted which in your case obviously should be 2017. This will solve the problem by automatically limiting range of available values to be lower bounded by 2017-01-01 - this for UWP DatePicker.

In WPF `DatePicker` there is a `DisplayDateStart` property which can be set to minimum date available in drop down calendar which can be chosen by user. Similar property `DisplayDateEnd` is used for setting highest date which can be displayed in DatePicker. `DatePicker.SelectedDateChanged` is a very useful event which when wired up will capture changes to the dates on all instances of DatePickers and this can be used to create relations between them i.e. to enforce selection of the valid period which starts from date selected on DatePicker 1 and ends on date selected in DatePicker 2 by setting DisplayDateStart on picker 2 to date selected on picker 1 in event handler. This all together provides very high level of flexibility in controlling user input via DatePicker class.

Comment: Just to complement your answer, in WinForms DateTimePicker the property is   DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime and it's default Minimum Value is 1753-01-01 and cannot be older; that generate some nasty bugs if you use a common model between, say, a MVP Form and a MVVM WPF application.

Comment: Ahn, almost forgot: the null Date in Outlook is 4501-1-1... that adds up to the nasty bugs when you automatize Office things...